# "Missing File" warning in Xcode 5 & 6 in iOS

Tags: ios

I am working with Xcode 6. I am creating new project & adding some files in my project, again i deleted that file with "Remove Reference" click and adding some new files according to my requirement. But when i run this App in Xcode 5 then its showing 2 warning with "Missing File" but if i run with Xcode 6 then its showing so many warning.

How Can i resolve this warning.

I share my screenshot how i deleted file.

[image]

This is my warning image

I googled but i got all answer with SVN but i am not using svn and my project also not in SVN server. So without SVN how can i resolve this.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Try to delete project.xcworkspace and clean and build

Comment: where is project.xcworkspace ?

Answer (score 21):

Run the shell script below in your SVN repositories path:

```sh
for missingFile in $(svn status | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//')
do
      echo $missingFile
      svn rm --force $missingFile
done
```

Comment: how to excute this files

Answer (score 6):

I can resolve these Missing File warnings just by doing an SVN update (Source Control -> Update), typically after a Commit.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Project Folder then right Click on it [image]

then Delete the XCUserda

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Xcode's source control was the culprit for 546 "missing files" warnings on any new project I created. Somehow it searches for the files of other projects I have in a remote SVN server.

In Xcode preferences, source control, I disable it entirely. Now I can create new projects without receiving missing files warnings.

Xcode's source control seems not to work so well, or at least it's not so clear about the way it does things, so I prefer external options to manage my repositories.